# I wonder what is wrong with firing bullets this way

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

this is the init method of the enemyShip class where I alloc/init the bullets before I fire the in the enemyShoot method below.

```
-(id) init
    {
        // always call "super" init
        // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
        if( (self=[super init]) ) {
            CGSize windowSize =[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
            [self initWithFile:@"Spaceship_tut.png"];
            [self setPosition:ccp(windowSize.width/2, windowSize.height - windowSize.height/9)];

        [self moveAround];
        self.bullet =  [[Bullets alloc] init];
        self.bullet1 =  [[Bullets alloc] init];
        self.bullet2 =  [[Bullets alloc] init];
        self.bullet3 =  [[Bullets alloc] init];
        self.bullet4 =  [[Bullets alloc] init];
        self.bullet5 =  [[Bullets alloc] init];

        myBullets = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:bullet1,bullet2,bullet3,bullet4,bullet5, nil];
        index = 0;
    }
    return self;
}




-(void)enemyShoot:(CCLayer*)theScene withThePoint:(CGPoint)whereTo

{
    NSArray *myBullets = [[NSArray alloc]  initWithObjects:bullet,bullet1,bullet2,bullet3,bullet4,bullet5, nil];
    bullet = [[Bullets alloc ] init];
    self.bullet = [myBullets objectAtIndex:index];
    self.bullet.position = self.position;
    [theScene addChild:bullet];
    id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0 position:ccp(whereTo.x,whereTo.y)];
    [self.bullet runAction:action];
    index++;
    if (index == 4) {
        index = 0;
    }


}
```

this is in an enemyShip class; the ship is able to fire bullets and this is the method that allows it to do that. Below is the init method for the bullet in the bullet.m file

```
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        self = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemyBullet2.png"];

        }

    return self;
}
```

the question is why do you guys think I get this error

```
"Assertion failure in -[Level2 addChild:z:tag:], /Users/dulybon1/Documents/DEVELOPER/lesson1/lesson1/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:355"
```

which I think means the object does not exist in memory after a few shots fired by the enemy.
and here is how this function gets called in the game layer; this function is called continuously in the init method using:

[self schedule:@selector(continuousShooting:)];

```
-(void)continuousShooting:(ccTime)dt
{
    [enemyShip enemyShoot:self withThePoint:ccp(myShip.position.x,myShip.position.y -200)];

}
```

Comment: "which I think means the object does not exist in memory " - sigh. Open CCNode.m file and read 355th line.

Comment: Also, what on earth you think are you doing in your init? First you initialize `self` with superclass's init, and then you _replace_ it with CCSprite.

Comment: thats right I changed that last night. Thank you Kreiri

Answer (score 0):

You can add your bullets to the scene in the init method and position them offscreen when they're not used or make them hidden. You can hide the bullets at the end of your action and show them at the begin of your action.

You might want to cleanup your code, you keep retaining bullets without releasing any of them. Why do you create an array in init to then create a new array in enemyShoot?

Why you have the following line in enemyShoot if you don't do anything with the variable?

```
bullet = [[Bullets alloc ] init];
```

Here you can follow a tutorial that includes shooting bullets (lasers): http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys I cleaned up the code a little bit and this is what the new enemyShoot looks like and it seem to work. I also removed the initializing of the bullets and the nsarray from the init method.
thank you again guys

-(void)enemyShoot:(CCLayer*)theScene withThePoint:(CGPoint)whereTo

```
{
    self.bullet =  [Bullets spriteWithFile:@"enemyBullet2.png"];
    self.bullet1 =  [Bullets spriteWithFile:@"enemyBullet2.png"];
    self.bullet2 =  [Bullets spriteWithFile:@"enemyBullet2.png"];
    self.bullet3 =  [Bullets spriteWithFile:@"enemyBullet2.png"];
    self.bullet4 =  [Bullets spriteWithFile:@"enemyBullet2.png"];
    self.bullet5 =  [Bullets spriteWithFile:@"enemyBullet2.png"];

    myBullets = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:bullet,bullet1,bullet2,bullet3,bullet4,bullet5, nil];
    self.bullet = [myBullets objectAtIndex:index];
    self.bullet.position = self.position;
    [theScene addChild:bullet];
    id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0 position:ccp(whereTo.x,whereTo.y)];
    [self.bullet runAction:action];
    index++;
    if (index == 4) {
        index = 0;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",bullet);
```

}